# Return single nested array object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've been wrestling with this all morning. I'm trying to pull a single nested object from an array. I've been [following along with the mongo query docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/), but I cannot return the desired object.

**videocollection**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID("95738ax1795b45f0hgn8dbfd8"),
  "playlist": [
    {
      "videos": [
        {
          "title": "Video Title 1",
          "slug": "video-1"      
        },
        {
          "title": "Video Title 2",
          "slug": "video-2"
        }
      ],
      "related": [
        {
          ....
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the following queries in the MongoDB CLI I either get zero result returned or the entire document.

```
db.videocollection.find({}, { $elemMatch: {'playlist.videos.slug':'video-2'} } )

db.videocollection.find({}, {_id: 0, 'playlist.0.videos': {$elemMatch: {'slug': 'video-2' }}})
```

I'm trying to query against the `slug` in the videos array.

Comment: Do you want the entire `playlist` for with the `videos` having just the matching sub document? Please post an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The proper query would be:

```
db.videocollection.find({ 'playlist.$.videos': { $elemMatch: { 'slug': 'video-2'} } })
```

The `$` is the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/positional/) and represents any index in an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still comes back empty when I run it through the CLI. I'm on mongo 3.2.1

Comment: This has been fixed. `$elemMatch` operates on an array. My earlier solution selected a single element.